# How does EMR pass the file to a mapper written in ruby?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, emr

I am trying to write a EMR mapper in ruby, however I am unclear what parameter the file from the S3 bucket would be passed in as. 
My current code just uses:

```
require 'optparse'

options = {}
opts.parse(ARGV)
...
inputFile = options[:input]
mode = options[:mode]
downloadPrefix = options[:prefix]
```

However, this job fails when I try to create a test workflow through the aws console. So my question is, how does EMR pass the input parameter to the mapper script for ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses STDIN, so:

```
STDIN.each_line do |line|
   puts line
end
```